# Swift 3: Convert SHA256 hash string to SecCertificate

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, keychain

`Alamofire` allows pinning using certificates as well as public keys (though the function to get public keys from the bundle gets the keys from the certificates in the bundle).

I am able to make the pinning work when the public keys are extracted from the certificates, **but the pinning fails when I supply a `SHA256` `String` as a public key** (I receive the key string from an api call and its is supposed to be used as a public key if the first pinning fails.) I use the code below to convert the string to a [SecKey]

//Create server trust policy

```
let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
                destinationURL!: .pinPublicKeys(
                    publicKeys:savePublicKeys(),
                    validateCertificateChain:true,
                    validateHost:true
                )]
            self.manager = SessionManager(
                serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies))
```

//Get [SecKey]

```
func savePublicKeys() -> [SecKey]
{
    var key:SecKey?
    var publicKeys:[SecKey] = []


    //Check and use if backup key is received from beacon call
    if(KeychainService().checkIfKeyExists(tag: "backupURL"))
    {
        key = KeychainService().obtainKey(tag: backupURLKey)
        publicKeys.append(key!)
    }

    return publicKeys

}
```

//Functions to insert and retrieve keychain data

```
  func insertPublicKey(publicTag: String, data: Data) -> SecKey? {
    let query: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
        String(kSecAttrKeyType): kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
        String(kSecClass): kSecClassKey as CFString,
        String(kSecAttrApplicationTag): publicTag as CFString,
        String(kSecValueData): data as CFData,
        String(kSecReturnPersistentRef): true as CFBoolean]

    var persistentRef: AnyObject?
    let status = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, &persistentRef)
    if status != noErr && status != errSecDuplicateItem {
        return nil
    }

    return obtainKey(tag: publicTag)
}

func obtainKey(tag: String) -> SecKey? {
    var keyRef: AnyObject?
    let query: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
        String(kSecAttrKeyType): kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
        String(kSecReturnRef): kCFBooleanTrue as CFBoolean,
        String(kSecClass): kSecClassKey as CFString,
        String(kSecAttrApplicationTag): tag as CFString,
        String(kSecReturnPersistentRef): true as CFBoolean
    ]

    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &keyRef)

    switch status {
    case noErr:
        if let ref = keyRef {
            return (ref as! SecKey)
        }
    default:
        break
    }

    return nil
}
```

Where am I going wrong? From what I know, the `String` I use is a `base64encoded` one and works in the Android part.

Comment: I have added a basic explanation, for why this would be difficult, as an answer here. While I do want people to be informed about hashing and security, this might devolve into a debate about cryptography and mathematics. If the moderators feel it right, they can lock this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for others who might stumble around trying to find the answer to the same or similar question.

**Short Answer:** Hashing is kind of a one way street. While *theoretically* you might be able to try different inputs to get the hash and thus get the certificate data as desired in the question, *realistically* it is very difficult to do so. Hashing algorithms have been written to prevent exactly the thing you want to achieve here. To get the desired input, you might have to spend humongous amount of time, space and computing power.

**Long Answer** Read up more on what hashing really does.

For example, for SHA256 in the question there are 22562256 possible hashes. There is a 50% chance if you tried 22552255 different inputs. Even if you tried one every microsecond, this would take you 10631063 years. That is one of the major reasons why this is realistically difficult to achieve.

Reversing a hash is like trying to guess two numbers from their sum (x+y = 234). There are a *lot* of possible combinations.
There are some great answers [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30481/why-cant-i-reverse-a-hash-to-a-possible-input?rq=1)